# Create new workspace in Terraform Cloud without any existing workspace through CLI

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-cloud

I'm setting up ephemeral review environments on GitLab MRs through Terraform and GitLab CI.  I use Terraform Cloud as a backend. I want to create a workspace for each of the review env and do it dynamically based on some environment variables in GitLab CI.

My problem is that I cannot create a new Terraform Cloud workspace through the CLI without having an existing workspace first. It seems counterintuitive since I have no use of that workspace. If a workspace exist I can run `terraform init`, then `terraform workspace new` and the workspace is created in Terraform Cloud. If I don't create a workspace first `init` doesn't work as no workspace exist and if I want to run `terraform workspace new` before it yells because `init` hasn't been run first. My configuration is:

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "my-org"

    workspaces {
      tags = ["review", "customer:test-frontend"]
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can create a workspace first through the API but that's cumbersome. I tried using `TF_WORKSPACE` but it should point to an **existing** workspace which is not my case. My current solution is switching to:

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "my-org"

    workspaces {
      name = "<TF_WORKSPACE>"
    }
  }
}
```

Using `sed` to replace that token with the dynamic name before calling `terraform init`.

Is there a way to do it through the CLI? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I also need to dynamically set the Terraform Cloud workspace inside an automated CICD.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to add an answer with what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. In my CI I do:

```yaml
environments:
  WORKSPACE: "${CI_PROJECT_NAME}_review_${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}"
before_script:
  - TF_WORKSPACE=empty-state-for-init terraform init -input=false
script:
  - terraform workspace select $WORKSPACE || terraform workspace new $WORKSPACE
  # then run terraform apply or whatever you want to do with your workspace
```

When I want to destroy my workspace and all associated infra, I do:

```yaml
script:
    - terraform workspace select $WORKSPACE
    - terraform destroy -input=false -auto-approve
    # We cannot delete a workspace if it's the current one
    - terraform workspace select empty-state-for-init
    - terraform workspace delete $WORKSPACE
```

In my projects, the Terraform configuration has:

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "my-org"

    workspaces {
      tags = ["review"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing Terraform Cloud workspaces with Terraform CLI workspaces.

> Note: Terraform Cloud and Terraform CLI both have features called "workspaces," but they're slightly different. Terraform Cloud's workspaces behave more like completely separate working directories.

https://www.terraform.io/cli/workspaces

When using Terraform Cloud, a Terraform Cloud workspace is required.
The usage of Terraform CLI workspaces is optional.

https://www.terraform.io/cloud-docs/workspaces#terraform-cloud-vs-terraform-cli-workspaces

Comment: I believe once you are connected to Terraform Cloud the terraform workspaces CLI allows you to manage Terraform Cloud Workspaces. But yes I agree, you don't HAVE to use the CLI but this I need totally dynamic workspaces from a same configuration, I need to.